# Creating a jar in a maven project using InteliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I'm all new to java and need to create an executable jar from InteliJ.
It is a maven project and I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong.
When creating the jar using right-click on src folder and choosing "Make Module" everything is ok and I can run it on the UNIX machine. BUT when I'm using the maven->Lifecycle->install I get an error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: taglib/Tagger
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:10)
```

few more things: this project using another jar created with "install", when opening the pom.xml file I get the pom of the other project (stated before).

As I said I'm very new to all of this and especially maven and would like to understand.

Regards.

Comment: please show your directory structure (project) and your pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

If its a maven project, you can simply create jar by using command `mvn clean install` from cmd, provided you have set your PATH variable properly. It will delete target directory and publish new jar there.

Comment: as I said for some reason that I don't understand the install doesn't work for me as i described.

Comment: You can run the same install command from cmd, provided you set maven in your system's path variable.

Comment: Unless there is something very fundamental that I do not understand: how can it be if install doesn't  work then how would it work all of the sudden? It does not make any sense to me.

Comment: This is quite simple, it might be possible that embedded maven inside your IDE is not working due to build path issues, which are quite common in eclipse. Either you can try to clean your eclipse's classpath or can proceed the way which i prefer.